# Limit sup of complex function

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, limsup-and-liminf

I wold like to determine this kind of limit sup:
$$
\lim \sup_{\mid z \mid \to \infty } \left \{  \frac{\mid b(t)\mid}{\mid z - a(t)\mid} \right \}
$$ 
Where $z \in \mathbb C$ such that $\mathrm{Re}z \geq 0$, $a$ and $b$ are two continuous  real functions in some bounded interval $I$.
What I have do:
\begin{align*}
\lim \sup_{\mid z \mid \to \infty } \left \{  \frac{\mid b(t)\mid}{\mid z - a(t)\mid} \right \}&= \lim_{\mid z \mid \to \infty }  \left[\sup \left \{  \frac{\mid b(t)\mid}{\mid z' - a(t)\mid}, \mid z' \mid  > \mid z \mid   \right \} \right] \\
&\leq \lim_{\mid z \mid \to \infty }  \left[\sup \left \{  \frac{\mid \max ( b(t))\mid}{\mid z'\mid  - \mid \max (  a(t))\mid}, \mid z' \mid  > \mid z \mid   \right \} \right] \\
&= \lim_{\mid z \mid \to \infty }  \left( \frac{\mid \max ( b(t))\mid}{\mid z\mid  - \mid \max (  a(t))\mid}  \right) \\
&=0
\end{align*}
I have some confusion about this calcul or is there another method?
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

No. It's just fine. You should have used the word “computation” instead of “calcul”. The rest is just as it should be.